# Ignition Gazebo Not Working

Tags: ubuntu, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress

[image]

As shown here in this image, my Ignition Gazebo doesn't display anything(grid, world, entites etc.) but a gray background.  I have re-installed gazebo several times and it still shows the same. What is the problem here?

The operating system is Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm using it on VMWare 17.5.